# Longest word in string

Tags: c, string

How can I find length of longest word in const char string without using auxiliary string?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int longest(const char *str) {
    int max = 0, prev = 0, final_max = 0;
    
    while (*str != '\0') {
        prev = max;
        max = 0;
    
        while (1) {
            if (*str != ' ') 
                max++;

            str++;

            if (*str == ' ') 
                break;
        }
    
        if (prev > max)
            final_max = prev;
    
        str++;
  }

  return final_max;
}

void main() {
    const char str[] = "Longest word in string";
    printf("%d", longest(str));
}
```

This prints `4` as length of longest word. Could you help me fix this?

Comment: Are you asking for an optimised algorithm or to fix the current code that doesn't work regardless of performance? Please ask only one thing per post and make it clear which it is.

Comment: Your infinite loop doesn't break on reaching the null byte at the end of the string; that's worrying, at least.

Comment: I thought my algorithm was fast but it has some errors, so I wanted to challenge stack overflow users to make it even more faster with correct output

Comment: You can find the longest word in linear time. Just iterate over the string and maximize the answer everytime the current character is a space.

Comment: Basic algorithm: for each word in the string loop if this word is longer than the previous longest then record the new longest end if end loop; return the longest.

Comment: @heitor could you post it as answer? I need very fast solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the longest word in linear time. This is surely optimal since any algorithm has to process every character at least once.

The basic idea is to loop over every character of the string, keeping track of the position of the last space (or any other word separator). Everytime the current character is a space we update the answer.

Note that we need to add an extra check at the end for the case where the longest word is the last in the string (and thus is not necessarily followed by a space).

Here's a simple implementation:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

size_t longest(const char *str) {
  size_t i, last=-1, ans=0;
  for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    if (str[i] == ' ') {
      if (ans < i-last) ans = i-last-1;
      last = i;
    }
  if (ans < i-last) ans = i-last-1;
  return ans;
}

void main(){
  printf("%zu\n", longest("Longest word in string")); // 7
}
```

Comment: You are missing an opening brace after `for (i = last = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)`

Comment: @Chris actually, there's no need for braces since there's just a single statement inside the loop

Comment: Right you are. Though I do personally prefer consistent brace style to avoid exactly that kind of confusion.

Comment: fair enough. guess it's more of a matter of taste

Answer (score 0):

Simply walk the string once.

After walking past white spaces, note the beginning of a word.  After walking through a word, note its length and compare to the current longest length.  Do this until a null character detected.

Use `size_t`, rather than `int` to handle *long* strings.

Access the characters via an `unsigned char*` to properly use `isspace()`.

Example:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t longest1(const char *str) {
  // Print up to 30 characters of str - for debug
  printf("<%.30s> ", str);

  size_t longest_length = 0;
  // Access the string as if it had unsigned chars.
  const unsigned char *s = (const unsigned char*) str;

  while (isspace(*s)) {
    s++;
  }

  while (*s) {
    const unsigned char *start = s;
    do {
      s++;
    } while (!isspace(*s) && *s);
    size_t length = (size_t) (s - start);
    if (length > longest_length) {
      longest_length = length;
    }
    while (isspace(*s)) {
      s++;
    }
  }
  return longest_length;
}
```

Tests

```
int main(void) {
  printf("%zu\n", longest("Longest word in string"));
  printf("%zu\n", longest(""));
  printf("%zu\n", longest(" "));
  printf("%zu\n", longest("  "));
  printf("%zu\n", longest("a"));
  printf("%zu\n", longest(" b"));
  printf("%zu\n", longest("c "));
  printf("%zu\n", longest("dd e"));
  printf("%zu\n", longest(" ff g"));
  printf("%zu\n", longest("hh i "));
  printf("%zu\n", longest("j kk"));
  printf("%zu\n", longest(" l mm"));
  printf("%zu\n", longest("n oo "));
  char *buf = malloc(INT_MAX * 2u);
  if (1 && buf) {
    memset(buf, 'x', INT_MAX * 2u - 1);
    buf[INT_MAX * 2u - 1] = '\0';
    printf("%zu\n", longest(buf));
    free(buf);
  }
}
```

Output

```
<Longest word in string> 7
<> 0
< > 0
<  > 0
<a> 1
< b> 1
<c > 1
<dd e> 2
< ff g> 2
<hh i > 2
<j kk> 2
< l mm> 2
<n oo > 2
<xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx> 4294967293
```

Comment: That seems like a complicated algorithm.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It is in effect a state machine, with minimal work.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with two closely related algorithms, one that only reports the length of the longest word but not where it is located, and the other which does both.  The bookkeeping tracks the longest word found so far and the current word — in the first case, just the length; in the second, both the length and the starting point.

#### Length — no position

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static size_t longest(const char *str)
{
    size_t max_len = 0;
    size_t cur_len = 0;
    for (char c = 0; (c = *str) != '\0'; str++)
    {
        if (!isspace(c))
            cur_len++;
        else
        {
            if (cur_len > max_len)
                max_len = cur_len;
            cur_len = 0;
        }
    }
    if (cur_len > max_len)
        max_len = cur_len;
    return max_len;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *data[] =
    {
        "a",
        "a bc",
        "ab c",
        "a b c",
        "a2345678 b234567 c23456789",
        "a234  b234    c234   ",
        "   a234  b2345  c23456  ",
        "",
        "      ",
        "   xxxxxxxxx1xxxxxxxxx2xxxxxxxxx3xxxxxxxxx4xxxxxxxxx5xxxxxxxxx6   ",
    };
    enum { NUM_DATA = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_DATA; i++)
        printf("LW = %3zu: [%s]\n", longest(data[i]), data[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
LW =   1: [a]
LW =   2: [a bc]
LW =   2: [ab c]
LW =   1: [a b c]
LW =   9: [a2345678 b234567 c23456789]
LW =   4: [a234  b234    c234   ]
LW =   6: [   a234  b2345  c23456  ]
LW =   0: []
LW =   0: [      ]
LW =  60: [   xxxxxxxxx1xxxxxxxxx2xxxxxxxxx3xxxxxxxxx4xxxxxxxxx5xxxxxxxxx6   ]
```

#### Length and position

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static size_t longest_word(const char *str, char const **word)
{
    size_t max_len = 0;
    size_t cur_len = 0;
    const char *max_word = 0;
    const char *cur_word = 0;
    for (char c = 0; (c = *str) != '\0'; str++)
    {
        if (!isspace(c))
        {
            if (cur_word == 0)
                cur_word = str;
            cur_len++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (cur_len > max_len)
            {
                max_len = cur_len;
                max_word = cur_word;
            }
            cur_len = 0;
            cur_word = 0;
        }
    }
    if (cur_len > max_len)
    {
        max_len = cur_len;
        max_word = cur_word;
    }
    else if (max_word == 0)
        max_word = str;
    *word = max_word;
    return max_len;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *data[] =
    {
        "a",
        "a bc",
        "ab c",
        "a b c",
        "a2345678 b234567 c234567890",
        "a234  b234    c234   ",
        "   a234  b2345  c23456  ",
        "",
        "      ",
        " x xxxx-xxxx1xxxx-xxxx2yyyy-yyyy3yyyy-yyyy4  x   ",
        "   xxxxxxxxx1xxxxxxxxx2xxxxxxxxx3xxxxxxxxx4xxxxxxxxx5xxxxxxxxx6   ",
    };
    enum { NUM_DATA = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_DATA; i++)
    {
        const char *word;
        size_t len = longest_word(data[i], &word);
        printf("LW = %2zu: [%.*s] in [%s]\n", len, (int)len, word, data[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
LW =  1: [a] in [a]
LW =  2: [bc] in [a bc]
LW =  2: [ab] in [ab c]
LW =  1: [a] in [a b c]
LW = 10: [c234567890] in [a2345678 b234567 c234567890]
LW =  4: [a234] in [a234  b234    c234   ]
LW =  6: [c23456] in [   a234  b2345  c23456  ]
LW =  0: [] in []
LW =  0: [] in [      ]
LW = 40: [xxxx-xxxx1xxxx-xxxx2yyyy-yyyy3yyyy-yyyy4] in [ x xxxx-xxxx1xxxx-xxxx2yyyy-yyyy3yyyy-yyyy4  x   ]
LW = 60: [xxxxxxxxx1xxxxxxxxx2xxxxxxxxx3xxxxxxxxx4xxxxxxxxx5xxxxxxxxx6] in [   xxxxxxxxx1xxxxxxxxx2xxxxxxxxx3xxxxxxxxx4xxxxxxxxx5xxxxxxxxx6   ]
```